# Equality Operator Overloading in Allegro

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, allegro

One of my friends is trying to overload an equality operator for comparing colours in Allegro, however it does not work,He gets the error "no match for operator==" This is overloaded outside the Color class/struct, the overloaded operator function is shown below:

```
typedef ALLEGRO_COLOR Color;
bool operator==(const Color& rhs) const
{
 if(_col.a==rhs.a && _col.b==rhs.b && _col.g==rhs.g && _col.r==rhs.r)
 return true;
 else
 return false;
}
.
.
.
//Data member
Color _col
```

Im thinking this does not work because the operator is defined & implemented outside the `ALLEGRO_COLOR` in Allegro,right? How can this problem be solved, is it possible to overload outside the Allegro Color struct.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete program that illustrates your problem? Judging by your code excerpt, it seems that your `operator==` is a member function of some class; is that correct?

Comment: While it's nice to know that you're doing this for "your friend", this sort of detail is probably not necessary on SO. Generally, the shorter a question, the better.

Answer (score 3):

`operator==` is a binary operator, but you only have one parameter. Try this:

```
bool operator==(const Color& _col, const Color& rhs) { ... }
```

---

**Postscript**: code of this form:

```
if ( condition )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

is needlessly verbose in C++. Better to do this:

```
return condition;
```

In your case, I'd prefer to see:

```
return _col.a==rhs.a && _col.b==rhs.b && _col.g==rhs.g && _col.r==rhs.r;
```

Comment: I clearly mistook his member-of-some-unnamed-class `operator==` for a poorly-coded non-member function. I think I'll wait for OP to post a more nearly complete example before correcting myself, though.

Comment: This will work, but there are two other things to consider: 1) r/g/b are floats (0.0-1.0), so you may want to introduce a delta value for a fuzzy match. Or not. Depends what you want to do. 2) Colors also have an alpha (a) value.