# Checking pixel color Allegro 5 C++

Tags: c++, allegro5

I want to check if a pixel on the screen is red or not . I am using allegro 5 . Here is my code

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap ;
int x , y;

x=*xIter-20;
y=*yIter;

ALLEGRO_COLOR red_color = al_map_rgb (255,0,0);
ALLEGRO_COLOR new_color = al_get_pixel (bitmap , x , y);

if(new_color==red_color)
    return 1;
```

But it reports a sytnax error

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'ALLEGRO_COLOR' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Comment: Looks like it isn't implemented. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7406353/516138

Comment: Could [this](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/607895) be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char r,g,b;
al_unmap_rgb(new_color, &r, &g, &b);

bool isColorRed = (r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't operator `==` for `ALLEGRO_COLOR` type, you need to implement it yourself.