# Allegro defining pixel color

Tags: c++, allegro5

How to define if for example a (100 , 100) pixel on the screen which I have created using Allegro function `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display=al_create_display(660, 660);` is red or no . How can I get the pixel's rgb properties with Allegro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the backbuffer with

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bitmap = al_get_backbuffer(display)
```

Combine that with what you have questioned in:
[Checking pixel color Allegro 5 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958922/checking-pixel-color-allegro-5-c/16959311#16959311)