# Getting pixel color from display in allegro5

Tags: colors, pixel, allegro5

I've been trying to check if pixel color is green and I've seen this:

[Checking pixel color Allegro 5 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958922/checking-pixel-color-allegro-5-c),

but I don't have bitmap in my code.

I was searching in allegro5 documentation and it seems like there's nothing which can help me.

Is there any solution to convert display to bitmap? Or to get pixel color from display? Anyone knows how to do it? I have position of my pixel and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`al_get_backbuffer`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_get_backbuffer) to get the display as a bitmap, then use [`al_get_pixel`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_get_pixel) to retrieve a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and i got some results

```
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap;
    bitmap = al_get_backbuffer(display);
    ALLEGRO_COLOR color = al_get_pixel(bitmap,x,y);

    bool isBlack = (color.r ==0 && color.g == 0 && color.b ==0);
    if(!isBlack){
        alive=0;
        explode() or something
    }
```